# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Admin})

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, jwt, middleware

I am getting the error below when loading admin page after logging-in to my react web app

> Blockquote

```
react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Admin}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:13231:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14133:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16997:1)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:17632:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19080:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
```

> Blockquote

JWT tokens are created on the backend after logging in. Here is the auth middleware code from my backend

```
const authJwt = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })
        
        
        if(!user) {
            throw new Error()
        } else{
        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        }
        return next()
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate' })
    }
}
```

And here is my middleware code for authenticating user role is admin from my backend:

```
const isAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
    const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(500).send({ msg: 'no user!' });
      }
    const roles = await Role.find({ _id: { $in: user.roles }})
        
          if (!roles) {
            return res.status(500).send({ msg: 'no role!' })
          }
          for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
            if (roles[i].name === "admin") {
              next();
              return;
            }
          }
          res.status(403).send({ message: "Require Admin Role!" });
          return;
        } catch (e) {
          return res.status(404).send(e)
        }
        }
```

My front end login auth service is as below:

```
class AuthService {
  login(Email, Password) {
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + "login", { Email, Password })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.accessToken) {
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }
        
        return response.data;
      }) 
  }
```

my user service is as below:

```
class UserService {
  getPublicContent() {
    return axios.get(API_URL + 'all');
  }
  getUserBoard() {
    return axios.get(API_URL + "user", { headers: authHeader() });
  }
  getModeratorBoard() {
    return axios
    .get(API_URL + "mod",)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("User", JSON.stringify(response.data))
      }
      return response.data
    })
  }
  getAdminBoard() {
    return axios.get(API_URL + 'admin', { headers: authHeader() });
  }
}
export default new UserService();
```

and lastly my auth header is as below:

```
export default function authHeader() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (user && user.accessToken) {
      console.log(user.accessToken)
      return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken };
    } else {
      return {};
    }
}
```

when I console log `user.accessToken` I get a string value with the value of the last JWT token generated when I logged in.

I am experienced in backend but relatively new react and front-end. Any help will be greatly appreciated here. Thanks in advance!

jsx rendering as on the admin page looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import UserService from "../services/user.service";
export default class BoardUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    UserService.getAdminBoard().then(
      response => {
        this.setState({
          content: response.data
        });
      },
      error => {
        this.setState({
          content:
            (error.response &&
              error.response.data &&
              error.response.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString()
        });
      }
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header className="jumbotron">
          <h3>{this.state.content}</h3>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Can you also include the code where you render the JSX to the screen?

Comment: I've added the jsx rendering

Comment: I'm making an answer instead of a comment due to the verbosity here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error rendering is fine (i.e., in your conditional, you either render a boolean or a string [message/toString()]). The problem seems to be coming from your response. When you set state to response.data, this will cause content to assume an object type (the object of the response). Unfortunately, JSX doesn't know how to render objects. You will have to take a look at your response.data and determine when you want to throw into content. Or, you can render a property inside content such as: `<h3>{this.state.content.some_property}</h3>`, but this can be a bit dangerous if content is undefined (before you receive the data from the server). Hope this helps!